# update list in application when service works

Tags: c#, wpf, service

So i have a service that creates letters and puts them in a database (sql-server).
I also have an application (c#,wpf) where there's a list with letters(from the database)

How can i trigger an event in the application if a new letter is made?
(so that the list should be updated)

Anyone who knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx).

The Introductory Videos are really helpfull, and you will need some sort of communication between the 2 applications.

I would suggest the letting the service allow client to subscribe to letter changes, and the server service(the one that puts letts in) to notify the clients about change of letters so the clients can refresh.

Comment: Thanks.
I knew it could be solved with WCF, but i thought there maybe was an easier way. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Only otherway would be to query the database at set intervals to see if it has changed, which would be ridiculous and bad program design.